# Should I always have 1 global database connection open in a Go web app? Or should I open and close it each time?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, go, web-applications

A **web** application in Go. Let's say it's a blog. Say there're 1000 sessions a day.

Should I create a global database connection and have it active all the time? Or should I open and close it each time there's a need to query a database? What's a general rule?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open *"The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB. "*

Comment: You should absolutely _not_ open and close each time. Whether you have a single connection or not is more an application question. Some applications need multiple connections (i.e. to different databases, or with different credentials)

Answer (score 2):

You should create a global connection object per app. This connection object is configured with connection pooling. Every connection object holds a certain number of connections as per configuration is given.

If you create and delete this for every request it will create and destroy the connection pool for every request.

Just create a global object of connection with required configurations using Singleton Pattern and it will internally manage connection pooling for you.

Also, handle the graceful shutdown of your app. When you get a signal for app termination action make sure you close the global connection object properly. Like this:-

```
    shutdown := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(shutdown, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGKILL)
    <-shutdown
    connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a sql connection pool to manage your connections. Golang database/sql package provide a mechanism for managing connection pool. Configuring your maxIdle param in database/sql package, so you can manage your free connection pool for the purpose of reusing when new connecting request is coming. The connection pool will open a new connection automatically when there is no free connection in the pool.

Comment: how to use connection pool?